Angular 17 : Issue with Using shared module Across Modules in Angular
I'm experiencing issues with using global components across different modules in my Angular application. Despite moving these components to a shared module, I'm encountering errors when trying to use them in other parts of the app.
exemple : components that are not a modules yet
when i move components from app.module.ts to shared.module.ts it works in the child modules but generates errors in other components that are not module yet
I have created a SharedModule where I declared and exported the global components. I then imported this SharedModule in the AppModule and other child modules. However, When moving components from app.module.ts to shared.module.ts it works in child modules but generates errors in other part pf application and i can't declare them in app.module.ts to shared.module.ts

first of all, if you are in Angular 17, consider moving to standalone components: https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components and get rid of modules logic. 2ndly, it's normal for it not to work properly, because you need to import your sharedModule inside other modules in order for your components to be loaded in theses other Modules.
